# Unable to run node js seneca microservice

Tags: node.js, api, microservices

I am new in node js. I try to run my first node microservice using seneca framework. But it shows following error

```
> npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-16-generic
> 
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
> 
> npm ERR! node v5.10.1
> 
> npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
> 
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> 
> npm ERR! myproject@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
> 
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> 
> npm ERR! 
> 
> npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@0.0.1 start script 'node server.js'.
> 
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
> installed.
> 
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myproject
> package,
> 
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> 
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> 
> npm ERR!     node server.js
> 
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
> project with:
> 
> npm ERR!     npm bugs myproject
> 
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> 
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls myproject
> 
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> 
> 
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> 
> npm ERR!     ~/Desktop/micro services/myproject/npm-debug.log
```

i use Seneca.js Yeoman generator to create this project. Please anyone help me.

my project directry looks like the following structure

```
        test-seneca
        |
        |-- client
        |   |-- css
        |   |-- js
        |   |-- partials
        |   |-- index.html
        |-- server
        |   |-- api.js
        |-- test
        |   |-- functional
        |-- bower.json
        |-- package.json
        |-- server.js
```

my package.json is

```
{

  "name": "myproject",

  "version": "0.0.1",

  "scripts": {

    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone && ./node_modules/.bin/bower install",

    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/functional/protractor.conf.js"

  },

  "dependencies": 
{

 "async": "^0.9.0",

    "hapi": "~8.2.0",

    "hapi-seneca": "^1.0.3",

    "seneca": "git://github.com/rjrodger/seneca.git",

    "seneca-account": "^0.1.8",

    "seneca-auth": "git://github.com/rjrodger/seneca-auth.git",

    "seneca-card": "^0.1.3",

    "seneca-project": "^0.1.4",

    "seneca-user": "~0.2.10"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "protractor": "~1.7.0",

    "bower": "~1.3.12"

  }

}
```

Comment: what is the command u are using to start the service

Comment: npm start for running the server

Comment: it start a few time then shows the error

Comment: please include the content of `package.json`

Comment: package.json has the following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it fails is because `yeoman` generator fails to install dependencies but fails silently.

If you look inside the `package.json` you can see the dependencies for `seneca-auth` and `seneca` pointing to non existing repo's. Please update those, and run `npm install` again.

**EDIT**

I suggest you **not** use this `yeoman` generator at all. It is outdated and might as well fail on your node version.

Comment: Which is the best way to do this. instead of yeomen.? i am new in node js

Comment: But still have an another problem api is not working.

Comment: please accept my answer first and create another question, cuz it is not related to current question